# install apache2-dev in ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: apache2

I try to install apache2-dev in this command:
`sudo apt-get install apache2-dev`
but it said:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package apache2-dev

That seems the is no package apache2-dev ?

I'm using ubuntu 13.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install apache2-dev on Ubuntu, use:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2-threaded-dev
```

**Source:** [Related question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939670/phusion-passenger-on-ubuntu-10-04-why-apache2-prefork-dev-when-we-want-apache2)

Comment: It gives unmet dependencies error:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apache2-dev : Depends: libapr1-dev but it is not going to be install
               Depends: libaprutil1-dev but it is not going to be ins
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.